# Content Go hidden on top in React

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm new to react. I am creating a cardlist with react bootstrap. Problem is no matter what I do When my list become larger it overflow and show like this.
**Note that my other half is hidden on top of the browser.**[image]

my fragment of code is below.

```
class Admin extends Component {
  render() {

    const examlist = exams ? (
      exams.map((exam) => {
        let tempTime = new Date(exam.startTime.seconds * 1000);
        let time = tempTime.toLocaleDateString("en-GB", {
          hour: "numeric",
          hour12: true,
        });
        return (
          <AddExamTab
            key={exam.id}
            title={exam.title}
            description={exam.description}
            id={exam.id}
            className={exam.class}
            time={time}
          />
        );
      })
    ) : (
      <div className="container">
        <h4>
          <Spinner />
        </h4>
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <AddExam />
        {examlist}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Maybe I have done somthing silly. what am I doing wrong here? Can anyone tell me? I'd be very grateful if anyone help me in this problem.

Comment: You are using some bootstrap class that limits the height of a div probably

Comment: Idon't think so. I have remove <div/> tag and replace them with <></>. Problem still persists

Comment: There must be some container (not necessarily a div) with some transform or overflow properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a React related problem, but a CSS related.

You should experiment with the parent div (with "container" class). Try to create your own class, add height and overflow properties.

Here is a small example of how you can implement that:

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #828282;
}

.container > div {
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  background-color: #929292;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>x1</div>
  <div>x2</div>
  <div>x3</div>
  <div>x4</div>
  <div>x5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Though my intuition says you are right but can you give an example of that.

Comment: I provided a small example, you can check it.

Comment: Thanks man It's working now. I didn't think it could be solved like this..